# stehen versus bestehen

Tags: usage, verb-usage

Is this incorrect?

> Es **steht** keine Frage darüber.

or should it be:

> Es **besteht** keine Frage darüber.

which would be consistent with most of the usage in DWDS, except for:

> Symbol OCR Deutscher Bundestag: Plenarprotokoll Nr. 07/225 vom 20.02.1976, S. 15670.
> Damit **stehen keine Fragen** der Nivellierung, der Rentenkürzung oder sonstiges zur Diskussion.

How should one view the differences in this usage? One is standard German and the other not? Or one is more common usage and the other less common, but still standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference in meaning

> Es steht keine Frage darüber

There is no question above it (e.g. on a sheet of paper)

> Es besteht keine Frage darüber

It is not in question

> Es stehen keine Fragen [...] zur Diskussion

There are no questions up for discussion

Answer (score 2):

In this context you actually need "bestehen" and not just "stehen". The example you quoted from DWDS is a bit misleading in this case, because it actually doesn't use "stehen" on its own as one might think. In fact, it uses the set phrase "zur Diskussion stehen", "to be up for discussion":

> Damit stehen keine Fragen [zu diesen Themen] zur Diskussion.
> With this, no questions [on these topics] are up for discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Please note, that without "zur Diskussion" the verb "stehen" does not make much sense in combination with "Frage":

1. > Es stehen keine Fragen zur Diskussion.
   > There are no questions for discussion.
2. > Es steht keine Frage darüber.
   > There is no question above it.
3. > Es besteht keine Frage darüber.
   > There is no question about it.

#3 is possible, but weak style.

The word "stehen" in #1 is part of the fixed phrase "etwas steht zur Diskussion" = "something is up for discussion".

Comment: But "Es steht außer Frage," makes sense. So why not, "Es steht keine Frage?"

Comment: @user44591: The multi-word expressions [außer Frage stehen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/außer%20Frage%20stehen) and [zur Diskussion stehen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/zur%20Diskussion%20stehen) are fixed phrases that are often used. But "keine Frage stehen" is just wrong. Sorry.

Comment: What rule establishes that "keine Frage stehen" is "wrong"? Is it impossible to understand? Does it violate a rule of grammar? If the rule is, "Germans just do not talk that way," since I am not German, that is a rule I cannot hope to achieve conformity with. The best I can hope for is to be understood, even if not respected for the attempt.

Comment: @user44591: The rule is the most powerful rule of all living languages. It is the main rule that is superior to all other rules: it is the actual usage of the native speakers. All other rules are only the weak attempt to interpret logic into a system, which in reality is not based on logic, but on custom.

Comment: Btw: You wrote: *"Germans just do not talk like that".* That's like talking about the peculiarities of the English language and saying, *"People from England just don't talk like that."* English is also spoken outside England, and German is also spoken outside Germany. 5 million people in Switzerland are native German speakers, and about 9 million Austrians (including me) are native German speakers. You can really piss off Swiss and Austrians by calling them *"Germans".*

Comment: My point was, that because I am not German, I cannot learn the language that Germans learn. I believe that is true of English, Swiss languages, etc. When you say I am "wrong", from my point of view that isn't helpful. I cannot learn the language as an infinite number of patterns. I can only learn a simplification thereof.

Comment: What do you make of this:   
Berliner Zeitung, 17.12.2001
Vielfach wirken die Fakten stumpf, weil vor ihrer pädagogischen Aufbereitung keine Frage steht, und ihr Zusammenhang erscheint naiv. Is not this a native speaker's usage?

Comment: @user44591: The number of pattern is not infinite. It is finite, but large. If you only want to learn a subset of it, then you German will stay weak, but then you also don't have the right to complain about patterns that native speakers use but which are unknown to you.

Comment: I am not complaining. Please let me know when you think otherwise, because that is not my intention. But I am frequently told that "patterns" that I find in bodies of German text are errors in German by the authors thereof. This creates an infinite space of patterns, because there appears to be no actual authority for the "true patterns". Some Germans write with them, others don't. I do not know how to make use of that information.